# How to write a statement without using using in C#

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I have a (debugging) need* to write the following single statement:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
// ...
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList().ForEach(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
```

but WITHOUT using usings, something like:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList().ForEach(x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x));
```

but this does not compile because ToList context is unknown:
error CS1061: 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My question is: how do I specify the namespace context for ToList()?

*This is a contrived example.  Practically I need a way to iterate over data/functions at runtime, in the debugger immediate window, and in some cases execution may not be within the context of System.Linq.

Using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Rather than talking about how you would do it in code, I would suggest focusing on the real requirements, which are really in the last paragraph. What happens when you try to do that in the debugger at the moment?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, if you move the caret to, say, `.ToList()` in the snippet above you can press F12 (Go to Definition) or Alt + F12 (Peek Definition) to display a reflected version of [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,947) or F1 to display something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist).  From either one you can determine the namespace and class in which the extension method is defined.

Comment: The problem with 'doing it in the debugger' is that in this particular case I wasn't debugging into code that I immediately had available and/or could recompile. I needed to evaluate the before/after effects of a change elsewhere on internal run-time generated data, and I wanted to see if I could generate comparison results at runtime w/o modifying the source.  I was hoping the Immediate Window could provide the means to do that, it apparently can't.  I was ultimately able to collect the data needed by adding some debug diag code further up the call stack and examining the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
    .ForEach(x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that in the Immediate window...

Comment: @RufusL - true, but it does answer the OP's question, just not their ultimate goal.

Comment: @Mosallem - adding some text explaining that extension methods can be called by directly referencing the static class in which the method is defined would improve your answer.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question.  Ultimately the call fails with the following: Evaluation of method System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32].ForEach() calls into native method System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsLogging(). Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.

Comment: @BretPehrson Yes, you're problem is that you are calling `Debug.WriteLIne`, which the debugger can't evaluate. But you can leave the `ForEach` off since the debugger will output the result for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can just call the extension methods as static methods:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
                      .ForEach(x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x));
```

However, you can't call `Debug.WriteLine` from the `ForEach` in the debugger, but the debugger will display the results anyway:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I found out, thank you.  Immediate Window has a lot of power, but not quite enough for my needs.